# How to change bot nickname with Discord.py rewrite?

Tags: python-2.7, discord, discord.py

The bot's nickname is never changed when using `client.user.edit(nick=name)` but prior commands and following commands are executed properly. Is there a different command I should use or maybe the parameter is incorrect?

I'm using the Discord.py-rewrite and have had success with `client.user.edit(username=name)` actually setting `username` to `name`, but that's not what I want. I need to change the nickname to avoid the discord cooldown for changing usernames.

```
def function(name):
  await client.user.edit(nick=name)
```

It should be changing the nickname just as the username is changed, but nothing happens. I'm not receiving an error either. I have the bot role permissions change nickname and manage nicknames set to true.

Comment: Nicknames are guild specific, so you'd need to refer to the guild member instance of the bot. Instead of client.user which isn't related to given guild, look into [Guild.me](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.me) as mentioned in the docs

Comment: Oh yeah that was exactly it, thanks so much!

Comment: Why did you tag `python-2.7` if you're using rewrite?

Answer (score 2):

await message.guild.get_member(self.user.id).edit(nick=name)

Get's the guild of the message that was sent and edits the nick of the bot member.

Comment: `message.guild.me.edit(nick=name)` should work, instead of fetching the member with `get_member()`

Comment: Ok, but what if you're not trying to change the bot's nickname during a message?

Answer (score -1):

```
import discord
import time
import asyncio
messages = joined = 0
def read_token():
with open("token.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    return lines[0].strip()

token = read_token()

client = discord.Client()


 async def update_stats():
 await client.wait_until_ready()
 global messages, joined

  while not client.is_closed():
     try:
        with open("stats.txt", "a") as f:
            f.write(f"Time: {int(time.time())}, Messages: {messages}, Members Joined: 
      {joined}\n")

        messages = 0
        joined = 0

        await asyncio.sleep(5)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        await asyncio.sleep(5)


         @client.event
        async def on_member_update(before, after):
      n = after.JOHN
     if n:
     if n.lower().count("tim") > 0:
        last = before.nick
        if last:
            await after.edit(nick=JOHN)
        else:
            await after.edit(nick="COOKIES")


        @client.event
        async def on_member_join(member):
       global joined
       joined += 1
       for channel in member.server.channels:
    if str(channel) == "general":
        await channel.send(f"""Welcome to the server {member.mention}""")


          @client.event
       async def on_message(message):
         global messages
     messages += 1

id = client.get_guild(ID HERE)
channels = ["commands"]
valid_users = ["JOHN#1234"]
bad_words = ["bad", "stop", "45"]

for word in bad_words:
    if message.content.count(word) > 0:
        print("A bad word was said")
        await message.channel.purge(limit=1)

if message.content == "!help":
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Help on BOT", description="Some useful commands")
    embed.add_field(name="!hello", value="Greets the user")
    embed.add_field(name="!users", value="Prints number of users")
    await message.channel.send(content=None, embed=embed)

if str(message.channel) in channels and str(message.author) in valid_users:
    if message.content.find("!hello") != -1:
        await message.channel.send("Hi") 
    elif message.content == "!users":
        await message.channel.send(f"""# of Members: {id.member_count}""")


          client.loop.create_task(update_stats())
        client.run(token)
```